# How to open URL inside the app by concatenation Strings?

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

In  my activity class:

final String input = slateURL + OtherHalfUrl;

//here I am combining my Strings to make it a complete Url

//for example slateURL = "http://example.com/id=" & OtherHalfUrl = 69

//So String input becomes  like this "http://example.com/id=69"

```
    Log.e("Complete URL", input);//in log I am checking and it is correct Url        



    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.loadUrl(input);//no output

 //  webView.loadUrl("http://example.com/id=69");//getting output
```

what is the reason for this or am I Doing something wrong.

```
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

OtherHalfurl I am getting from my other activity fragment  like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), GoToActivity.class);

 intent.putExtra("id",idno);
```

And getting it like this :

```
             String OtherHalfUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
webView.loadUrl(YOUR URL);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you Pravin it is working now..can you explain your solution @Pravin

Comment: yes just wait 6 more min...it is the min. time to accept the answer

Comment: @Pravin Please explain your code to make your answer more helpful :)

Comment: shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)-Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView.

Comment: for detail of shouldOverrideUrlLoading please visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: @Pravin This code perfectly work when there is a PDF but when there is an image it is showing blank